# Is it hard to learn all the rules here to be perfectly regular?

Tags: discussion

It seems for me, that my questions, if I would post them here, would be so unusual, inquisitive, or unique - some might not even have an answer - that I'm afraid my questions would be closed.

I like to push my knowledge and explore the edges of understanding. This is how my creative thought process works. I like to develop unique ideas, and not stop to worry about whether what I am doing is right, or following the rules, so there may not always be a perfect answer to my questions.

Question:
Sometimes I would like to ask usual questions, like everyone else. I feel it would be wrong to make another account if it was just to ask questions that would fit the correct format for the site.

- How much do people fear asking improperly formatted questions? And is this kind of fear stagnating?
- The whole picture of development: How do people develop in this kind of community, where the rules are enforced so strictly.

I could be downvoted out and ignored with my kind of far off thoughts. Maybe someone could recommend me to a better community for expressing my unique thoughts and ideas? However most don't seem to have the high quality professionals and resources as SE.

......

IMHO: It could be years before I learn your system in the proper way (besides there are two kinds of problems here:

- hierarchy highness problem (high score)
- somebody's memory about your un-seriousness and every person has his opinion (or opinion of the system in his comment, like stating rules).

Comment: I think my head just exploded.

Comment: Well while writing I was dissappointed of my thoughts so I stopped myself, and my part of head blocked for safety not to put good ending to my post, like playing safe/bad

Comment: As a unicorn, I get by.

Comment: sry for your head , rly, i'm not very good at life at all, just read all and read carefully

Comment: I think you need to organize your thoughts a bit before posting questions.  It's not at all clear what you're trying to say/ask.

Comment: @Servy  I don't think he speaks English as his primary language

Comment: @SamIam The problem appears to be what he's trying to say, not the way in which he's saying it, so that's not really the problem.

Comment: best I could do on the edit, someone else can take a stab at it.

Comment: I edited, for clarity, some of the changes are pretty massive, however I feel like they actually capture the intent of the OP.

Comment: Is that you, [Twirlip of the Mists](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/what-is-the-significance-of-hexapodia-is-the-key-insight)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be afraid to screw up. If you screw up a few times, as long as you have a history of good contributions, all you will get is a warning in the comments. If you screw up more, you may get a mod message. Screw up *too much*, and you may get a small ban (this is if you start continually posting bad questions)

Of course, if you feel *sure* that a question will be closed, don't ask it. If you're unsure, go ahead and ask. Or, ask on meta if it is on topic (this is the better option)

Don't create new accounts for this.

Answer (score 18):

1. Keep your questions clear, simple and brief.
2. Each site has a topic, an area of interest. *Stay on topic.*
3. It's up to you to make your questions clear, not on the community to read them carefully.
4. Don't make multiple accounts on the same site.
5. Stack Exchange is not a creative medium, for the most part; it is a place where questions can be answered.  If you're trying to create something by posting a question, or trying to start a discussion, or asking for opinions, you may be in the wrong place.

Comment: but i'm afraid to die.. if i post

Comment: @Xsi: It's ok we don't bite (byte?).  Hard.

Comment: You don't die here... only a few electrons get killed.

Comment: if multiple accounts i'll die( if only in ban more die

Comment: Don't make multiple accounts.  You need to try and make one account work.  You can do that by reading other people's questions, and see how they become successful with their questions.

Comment: @Xsi - it's really not that hard.  Just look around the SE site your using, and see how things go, which questions are successful, etc.

Answer (score 8):

If I may, I think you are asking:

> I ask two completely differnt kinds of questions here. Some are everyday ordinary questions and some are mindbogglingly unique and amazing. Should I use different accounts for different kinds of questions? Is it ok to ask both kinds of questions?

If that is your question, I would say

- no, don't create a second account. Especially don't do that so that your "main" account will be immune from punishments like downvotes or suspensions on your other account.
- most mindbogglingly unique and amazing questions are offtopic on these sites. Get familiar with the site by asking and answering ordinary questions, then consider stretching out a bit once you're established.

Further, it seems you are worried that some people will think less of you and ignore you (either not giving you answers or not giving you votes; I'm not sure which) either for the ordinary questions or for the amazing ones. It's fantastic that you feel a little bit nervous about that. So few askers do. The cure is to word all your questions, whether ordinary or edge-of-known-space as clearly and succintly as possible. You should also be open to editing them to clarify in response to comments or answers that demonstrate people aren't quite getting you. It's highly unusual for any user to be so unusual that the general mass of SO (hundreds of thousands of people) form an opinion of that user. Write well and relax.

Comment: `some are mindbogglingly unique and amazing` -- Not as much as you think they are.

Comment: I cannot afford myself to write decent questions twice I write and burn and next I rise - not here otherwise.